# BigQuery extract string between two "."

Tags: google-bigquery, data-analysis

I have three string types:
'en-ae.sssports.com','amazon.co.uk','farfetch.com'

I require the client name i.e. Sssports, Amazon, Farfetch from each.

Had tried using regexp '(?:.)[^.]*(?:.)' to extract string between the two dots but I require a dynamic code that extracts data from all three sting types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below query

```sql
SELECT INITCAP(RTRIM(NET.REG_DOMAIN(str), '.' || NET.PUBLIC_SUFFIX(str))) AS client_name
  FROM UNNEST(['en-ae.sssports.com','amazon.co.uk','farfetch.com']) str
```

##### Query reesults

```
+-------------+
| client_name |
+-------------+
| Sssports    |
| Amazon      |
| Farfetch    |
+-------------+
```

##### References

- [NET.REG_DOMAIN()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/net_functions#netreg_domain)

> Takes a URL as a STRING and returns the registered or registerable domain (the public suffix plus one preceding label), as a STRING.

- [NET.PUBLIC_SUFFIX()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/net_functions#netpublic_suffix)

> Takes a URL as a STRING and returns the public suffix (such as com, org, or net) as a STRING.